# Compute density fluctuations of particle distribution of a surface of 3D geometry

Tags: particles, export, geometry

I am using Cellblender to model bio molecular reactions within a 3D geometry that I created, but I am still a novice in Blender. As part of these simulations a fixed number of particles (my case N=60, here red and green dots on surface) is being placed randomly on the surface of a part of that geometry.

[image: Random placement of particles on surface]

Now I want to quantify and understand that random placement, i.e. compute the density fluctuations (the density itself is constant and given by rho = N/A = 60/ < surface area >) or ask questions like: what is the minimal distance of those particles on the surface? How far away are the particles apart on average on that surface? or create some bar plots for each particle on the surface with the minimal distance to the next particle. Or project the surface onto a flat plane and put the particle positions on that flat projection (distance loyal), etc - any kind of statistics or visualization would be appreciated.

Is there someway to do statistics of particles on surfaces in Blender? Computing distances on surfaces of 3D geometries is surely not a trivial thing, but since I am new to Blender I can not judge if its possible or not.  Or maybe there is some way to export the 3D data (geometry, particles positions) and then analyze it with another tool?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: **Possible?** Yes, probably **Easy?** I don't think so. As far as I know, I'm not aware of any builtin or native tools to preform this, but it might be possible through some unknown amount of Python scripting